# Not working delay in messages. Want to sending message with delay 3 seconds. But something is wrong

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, delay, message

```
#Partnering
@bot.command()
async def partnerstwo(ctx, *, member: discord.Member, message, amount = 1):
#Mast be a pinging an author message and member   
    Part = discord.Embed(title=f"Dziękujemy za partnerstwo {ctx.message_author} | Partnerem 
    jest {member.mention}")
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )
    await ctx.channel.send(message)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed = Part)
```

I have just problem with sending 2 message, and cmd does not write anything like an error.

Comment: So what's going wrong?

Comment: bot doesnt sending "await ctx.channel.send(embed = Part)"

Comment: Maybe try `ctx.send` instead of `ctx.channel.send`

Comment: still not working.